# Windows Form PictureBox Save Image and Background property

Tags: c#, windows, forms, picturebox

with a button i choose the Image (photo Frame) and i add the image to picturebox.image property
With other button i choose a Photo and i add the image to the same picturebox but to the picturebox.background

Whith another button i create a .jpg file
But only save the picture.image
need to save all..  .image with background.

do u know how can i save the picture with the background.
many thxs

[the image explain my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWV1r.jpg)

Comment: If it's not working then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, we can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this is the sort of thing you're after:

```cs
using (var compositeImage = new Bitmap(width, height))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(compositeImage))
{
    g.DrawImage(myPictureBox.BackgroundImage, 0, 0);
    g.DrawImage(myPictureBox.Image, 0, 0);

    compositeImage.Save(filePath);
}
```

You'll need to determine exactly what size to use for the composite image and the location to draw the original images.